# Centered figures in org-mode LaTeX export

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, org-export

When org-mode exports figures to LaTeX, the figure shows up left justified.  Is there an easy way to have all the figures centered?

I want to avoid having to type `#+ATTR_LATEX: :float t` above each figure.

I would simply like each `\includegraphics` in the exported LaTeX code to be wrapped in a `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` block.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add advice to `org-latex--inline-image`:

```
(advice-add 'org-latex--inline-image :around
            (lambda (orig link info)
              (concat
               "\\begin{center}"
               (funcall orig link info)
               "\\end{center}")))
```

Note that this puts *every* inline image in `\begin{center} ... \end{center}`, even ones that are centered already by setting `:float`.

Comment: This is not workin in Emacs 23. Any workaround?