# Setting #+ATTR_LATEX for all images of a document

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I am currently adding an `#+ATTR_LATEX` before every image in my org-file to center it in the produced LaTeX beamer slides. That is slightly annoying and clutters up the document.

Is there a way to set an `#+ATTR_LATEX` for all images or even just for the whole `.org` file?

Comment: What if you add `\usepackage{floatrow}` header?

Comment: Sounds like [this](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5363/centered-figures-in-org-mode-latex-export/5369) answered question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the `org-latex-image-default-option` variable.  Would that do for you?  I'm using a shell function for a fixed image width, perhaps you can use something similar:

```
orgexp()
{
    emacs  --batch -l ~/.emacs --eval \
           "(progn
             (setq org-latex-image-default-width \".4cm\"
                   org-export-allow-bind-keywords t
                   org-confirm-babel-evaluate nil)
             (find-file \"$1\") (org-latex-export-to-pdf))"
}
```

So I simply call

```
orgexp myorgfile.org
```

to get a PDF where all images are .4 cm wide.

Comment: That actually sounds like what I was looking for.